# Use Ajax to fetch data from MySQL database, and output data to a table

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have this code below, which fetches data from MySql database, and outputs data to a table.

```
</html>
<body>

<div class="box">

<table class="tb">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>DATE / TIME</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

    <?php

include("dbconfig.php");
session_start();
            $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE user='$login_session'";
            $rs = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $strSQL);
            $data = array();
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
           echo '<tr><td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
           echo '<td align="center">'.date("d.m.Y H:i:s A", $row['date']).'</td>';

      }

echo '</tbody></table>';

            mysqli_close($dbconfig);

    ?>
</table>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The problem is, when I make changes to the database, I need to refresh the website 3 or 4 times to see the new changes. I want to use Ajax to fetch and display data real-time. I also want to call Ajax and PHP on the same page as HTML.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes I did, unfortunately since I have very basic knowledge on programming, it did not work.

Comment: Did you simply try refreshing the browser cache `CTRL+F5` Remember code changes while developing, it does not when code goes LIVE

Comment: Add that under your question then. Maybe you did a small mistake,

Comment: Well the thing is I don't want to refresh the browser cache, I want it to update by itself.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend to use datatables instead and use the datatable.refresh(); function.